# Github action: An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory .. No such file or directory

Tags: flutter, github-actions

I am creating two flutter applications which share many functionality and decided to create a separate package for it to be used by both.

The following is the directory structure

- my_project

  - .github/workflows/main.yaml
  - apps

    - app1

      - lib/main_devnet.dart
    - app2

      - lib/main_devnet.dart
  - packages

    - graph

      - main.dart

The graph package have some codes which are generated by code_builder by running

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

In my computer everything works fine when building apks, But I was trying to automate this work with github actions.

Here is my current workflow with which I am having trouble getting it work.

.github/workflows/main.yaml

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - dev
      - alpha
name: "Build & Release"
jobs:
  generate: #THIS JOB WORKS FINE
    name: Generate codes
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v2
        with:
          distribution: 'zulu'
          java-version: '11'
      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          flutter-version: '2.10.0'

      - name: Installing graph dependencies
        working-directory: ./packages/graph
        run: flutter pub get

      - name: Generating code
        working-directory: ./packages/graph
        run: flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

  build: #THIS JOB FAILS
    needs: generate
    name: Build appps
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        dir: [ './apps/app1/','./apps/app2/' ]
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - name: Installing dependencies in apps
        working-directory: ${{ matrix.dir }}
        run: flutter pub get

      - name: Building apks
        working-directory: ${{ matrix.dir }}
        run: flutter build apk --debug lib/main_devnet.dart

      - name: Push to Releases
        uses: ncipollo/release-action@v1
        with:
          artifacts: "${{ matrix.dir }}/build/app/outputs/apk/debug/*"
          tag: v1.0.${{ github.run_number }}
          token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

When pushing my code to github I am getting the following error which causes CI to fail:

```
Run flutter pub get
  flutter pub get
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
Error: An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory '/home/runner/work/my-app-repository/my-app-repository/./apps/app2/'. No such file or directory
```

I think the problem relies in defining working directories using matrix as you can see in error
`my-app-repository/my-app-repository` this word *my-app-repository* is repeated twice and cause wrong dir and fail the whole process.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't you use the `actions/checkout` at the beginning of the second job as well?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thanks for response, I added it and now I am getting different error ````flutter pub get
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
/home/runner/work/_temp/ecd6d01b-44e9-4740-bb97-135a953c3977.sh: line 1: flutter: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.```

Comment: It's because each job use a new runner to run its steps operations. In your case, you also need to install flutter with the flutter-action on the second job as well.

Answer (score 6):

Each job starts with a new environment.

You have to checkout repository and install flutter on each of those jobs:

So you have to add this to steps in your matrix solution:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- uses: actions/setup-java@v2
  with:
  distribution: 'zulu'
  java-version: '11'
- uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
  with:
  flutter-version: '2.10.0'
```

Comment: To maintain the environment use different steps within a job

Comment: NB: actions/checkout@v2 recent version is `3`, so it's actions/checkout@v3

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is wrong at the working-directory path